# fullscreen button not appears in youtube video when opened in webview

Tags: video, webview, fullscreen

I can find the solution if fullscreen button is not responding but its not displaying itself.

I am displaying a webpage which has embedded youtube videos init in my simple `webview`, but the problem is that video from youtube does not show the `full screen button`.Is this problem of `android side` or `webpage side`?

Please share if you have solution. thanks in advance. Sharing a snapshot along with this[the sample image of youtube video displayed in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asfam.png)

Comment: did you find answer for this?